# How to adapt my route for a plugin

Tags: cakephp

I am looking since a moment the solution.

I have a plugin in

```
/app/plugin/acl_manager
```

I activate my plugin in bootstrap

```
CakePlugin::load('AclManager', array('bootstrap' => true));
```

When I change my URL to

> /cakephp/admin/acl_manager/acl/permissions

I can access my plugin
But I would like to have instead of the above URL to keep the same naming

> /cakephp/admin/permissions

I added a new line in my route.php but it does not work

```
Router::connect('/:action', array('plugin'=>'AclManager','controller'=>'acl','action'=>'permissions','acl'));
```

Some can help me with this?
For more information the plugin can be see here
[AclManager](https://github.com/FMCorz/AclManager)

Answer (score 0):

I think

`Router::connect('/:action', array('plugin'=>'AclManager','controller'=>'acl','action'=>'permissions','acl'));`

**is wrong here**, since in future if you've more routes then it will map every action to the `plugin`, `controller` & `action` you've specified above.

so better you can set the routing something like below.

```
Router::connect('/admin/permissions', array(
    'admin' => true, 'plugin'=>'AclManager',
    'controller'=>'acl','action'=>'permissions','acl'
));
```

**update**

```
Router::connect('/admin/:action', array(
    'admin' => true, 'plugin'=>'AclManager',
    'controller'=>'acl'
));
```

But make sure this route won't be affected by the other routes you've defined.

Comment: Hello, thank for your answer and it work really bette!!! When I enter my URL like /cakephp/admin/permissions et goes to desired page. Gooooood. But now all other links have a prefix like : http://localhost:8888/cakephp/admin/AclManager/supports and /AclManager/ should not be. It shoulkd be http://localhost:8888/cakephp/admin/supports :o|